Is a deck cleaner necessary after stripping paint and sanding?
We recently stripped all of the lead paint off of an old porch (possibly 100+yr old old growth wood deck) using Dumond's peel away and Lead Out paint strippers. We used mineral spirits and steel wool to scrub all of the stripper and loose paint off and generally are now down to bare wood. We also checked the pH per the Dumond stripper's instructions and used its neutralizer to bring the deck back to a balanced pH. After that, we sanded with 80 grit paper, repaired it using Abbatron and Minwax fillers depending on the repair type, sanded those repairs flush, and added wood harder to any high-risk areas. Next, we plan to sand using ~180 grit paper before priming it and repainting it with Behr's Porch and Floor Paint. We've been using a HEPA vacuum rated for lead dust removal, so the deck has little to no debris anywhere on it.
I keep seeing deck cleaners mentioned and wonder if we need to do that? This seems relevant to stained decks that have mildew and need a resealing, but after all the paint removal and sanding, do we need to clean this? Assuming it doesn't hurt, we're on a bit of a time crunch to get the deck primed and painted this week before traveling for the next three weeks and don't want to leave it exposed. Can we skip this step, or is there a strong case for doing this?

If down to the wood, you only need to make sure there is no dust/dirt/oil on the the wood.  A simple wash and/or wipe down.  Let dry and prime/paint/stain.
